# How to get a word that starts with a number in a sentence varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here it's a sample of my data, note that the word could be anywhere in the string:

```
   -- DDL and sample data population, start
    DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(100));
    INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
    ('abc 1XXXX xyz'),
    ('abc xyz 2XXXXXXXX'),
    ('3XX abc xyz');
    -- DDL and sample data population, end
```

The output should be:

```
+----+-----------+
| ID |  Result   |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | 1XXXX     |
|  2 | 2XXXXXXXX |
|  3 | 3XX       |
+----+-----------+
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You say to get the word *that starts with a number* - however in your sample data this doesn't seem relevant as your desired output is just the second word; do you have data such as 'abc xxx xyz' or 'abc xyz 3xxx xyz'? Or is the "starts with a number" a red herring?

Comment: You already have a proposed answer. Did you have a chance to try it?

Comment: Hey guys! I've updated the question due to your observations and help.

Comment: @javaMan, a minimal reproducible example needs all four ##1-4.

Comment: @miriamka my SQL Server version is: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU9) (KB5000642) - 15.0.4102.2 (X64)   Jan 25 2021 20:16:12   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS) <X64>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

The built-in [PARSENAME (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function is very handy for the task.

**SQL #1**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('abc 1XXXX xyz'),
('abc 2XXXXXXXX xyz'),
('abc 3XX xyz');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID
    , PARSENAME(REPLACE(tokens, SPACE(1), '.'), 2) AS Result
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------+
| ID |  Result   |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | 1XXXX     |
|  2 | 2XXXXXXXX |
|  3 | 3XX       |
+----+-----------+
```

**SQL #2, SQL Server 2016 onwards**

So the goalposts were moved in the middle of the game. That shows even more importance of the minimal reproducible example.

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('abc 1XXXX xyz'),
('abc xyz 2XXXXXXXX'),
('3XX abc xyz');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT * FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT IIF(TRY_CAST(LEFT(value,1) AS INT) IS NOT NULL, value, NULL) AS token
            FROM STRING_SPLIT(tokens, SPACE(1))) AS t(token)
)
SELECT * 
FROM rs
WHERE token IS NOT NULL;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------------------+-----------+
| ID |      tokens       |   token   |
+----+-------------------+-----------+
|  1 | abc 1XXXX xyz     | 1XXXX     |
|  2 | abc xyz 2XXXXXXXX | 2XXXXXXXX |
|  3 | 3XX abc xyz       | 3XX       |
+----+-------------------+-----------+
```

**SQL #3, SQL Server 2012 onwards**

```
DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT * FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
            REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
            ']]></r></root>' AS XML).query('
    for $x in /root/r
    return if (xs:int(substring($x,1,1)) instance of xs:int) then $x
         else ()
').value('(r/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')) AS t(token);
```

Comment: Hi Olivier! I've just updated the question. Thank you for the help! The word that starts with a numbers not always will be the second one.

Comment: Hi Miriamka! Thank you! But the function STRING_SPLIT it's only compatible with 130 versions or later :(

Comment: @javaMan, glad to hear that the proposed solution working for you. Please don't forget to mark  it as Answer.

Comment: @javaMan, what is your SQL Server version? It is the #4 on a list.

Comment: my SQL Server version is: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU9) (KB5000642) - 15.0.4102.2 (X64) Jan 25 2021 20:16:12 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS) <X64>

Comment: where did you learn to code like this: "']]></r><r><![CDATA[" or like this: "for $x in /root/r
    return if (xs:int(substring($x,1,1)) instance of xs:int) then $x"? That's some really advanced query, never heard before...

Comment: @javaMan, it is XQuery. Check it out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Here's a single one-line that accomplishes your substring requirements using `patindex`, `charindex` and `stuff`:

```
select id,
    Left(Stuff(tokens, 1, PatIndex('%[^A-z][0-9]%', tokens), ''), 
      IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(' ', Stuff(tokens, 1, PatIndex('%[^A-z][0-9]%',tokens), '')),0), Len(tokens)) ) as Result
from @tbl
```

[DB<>Fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d68ae8aa7754404ae9d31949cfddd9e3)

Comment: Please try it for the following `('X3X 7bc xyz')`

Comment: @miriamka Fair point and goalpost repositioned! Have edited above and the Fiddle to take that into account.

Comment: Also note this returns the first word starting with a number, your solution will return multiple rows if more than one word starts with a number. No idea if either is preferable as the OP's example data does not cover it.

Comment: Stu, Peace. .

Comment: @Stu, what's OP? I'm not so close to this terms yet :) Thank you so much!

Comment: OP - that's Original Poster... in this case, you 